# how to access Dartium's speech synthesis?

Tags: dart, dartium

I found the speech recognition API but not the speech synthesis in the dart SDK. Is it not exposed in Dartium? I need some sort of tts, I could use Google translate_tts but unfortunately Dartium does not play mp3. 
Any ideas on how to get some kind of tts in dart(web app) is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm not up to date, but i don't think there is any browser implementing the synthesis part of the WebSpeech API yet.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tts.html ?

If so, Dart doesn't yet have all of Chrome's extension and apps APIs natively wired up. In the meantime, you can use the JS-interop library (https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop) to access those APIs.

I haven't tried the tts API in Dartium, though.